# How to use image_proc node

Tags: ros, xtion, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Xtion on Ubuntu with ROS hydro. Ran openni2_launch to the launch camera drivers.

> $ rostopic list

/camera/rgb/image_raw

/camera/rgb/camera_info

and many other topics /camera/depth/.. camera/ir/..

> ROS_NAMESPACE=camera rosrun image_proc
> image_proc

tells me to advertise /camera/image_raw first.

[ WARN] [1426076094.517140381]: The input topic '/camera/image_raw' is not yet advertised

I was assuming my camera drivers are publishing to /camera/image_raw and camera/camera_info by default which I suppose image_proc will subscribe to publish image_mono or image_rect image but apparently they are publishing /camera/rgb/image_raw and camera/rgb/camera_info. What is the difference between /camera/image_raw and /camera/rgb/image_raw and  how should I publish /camera/image_raw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204751/how-to-use-image_proc-node/) by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your cam driver topics are

```
/camera/rgb/image_raw

/camera/rgb/camera_info
```

I guess you should start the image_proc node like:

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=camera/rgb rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

Update with explanations:

The `ROS_NAMESPACE=camera/rgb` puts all topics of the node into this namespace. Initially if you run

```
rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

it will listen to the topics

```
/image_raw

/camera_info
```

. If you than change the call into

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=camera rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

as mentioned in the tutorial it will listen to

```
/camera/image_raw

/camera/camera_info
```

. However, your camera driver apparently publishes to the /camera/rbg namespace so your call will be

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=camera/rgb rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

such that the image_proc node listens to the topics of your camera driver which are:

```
/camera/rgb/image_raw

/camera/rgb/camera_info
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2015-03-11**:
can you please explain what is actually happening?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-03-12**:
Please see the edit

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2015-03-12**:
thank you for the explanation. can you also give me the command list to convert depth image to XYZ point cloud using depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz nodelet of depth_image_proc.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-03-12**:
Sorry, don't know this. Please feel free to open new thread on that, if you can not find it in the docs/tutorials